# Keycloak - how to render custom page with some actions instead of the default error page for expired action token?

Tags: keycloak

When a user tries to use an action token that is expired (e.g. expired email verification link), Keycloak renders a default error page saying "Action expired.".

Is there an "official" way of rendering a custom page with actions like "resend email", "back to login" when an expired action token is detected by Keycloak?

I thought that maybe Keycloak would expose some attributes to the template error page that I could use to customize, but couldn't find anything useful.